# Unsubscribe from Kotlin Flow without cancelling current scope

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-lifecycle, kotlin-flow

I am subscribing to a Kotlin SharedFlow of booleans within a `repeatOnLifecycle` block in Android. I want to subscribe until I receive the first `true` boolean and act on it.

As soon as the first `true` boolean is received I need to unsubscribe and run the processing funtion within the lifecyce scope so it gets cancelled when the lifecycle transitions to an invalid state.

When I call cancel on the current scope and embed the processing code in a `NonCancellable` context it will not be cancelled on lifecycle events.

I think I would want something like a `takeWhile` inlcuding the first element that did not match the predicate.

Below are some sample flows where I want to collect all elements until the $ sign:

```
true $ ...
false, true $ ...
false, false, true $ ...
```

Sample code:

```kotlin
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
    repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
        flowOfInterest.collectLatest {
            if (it) {
                stopCollection()
                doOnTrue()
            } else {
                doOnFalse()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What is the correct/simplest way to achieve this behavior?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [first](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/first.html) function to continue collecting until the given predicate returns `true`.

```kotlin
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
    repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
        flowOfInterest.first { 
            if(it) doOnTrue() else doOnFalse()
            it 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank! I was not aware that first can also carry a predicate. I think this is very close to what I need however it does not return the elements not matching the predicate till the first match. I need all unmatching including the first matching elements.

Comment: You can create a mutable list and keep adding the items in the list inside the lambda. I don't understand what problem you are facing here. Could you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: I think you are right and `first` would work the same if I call the functions in the predicate, as in your example. I don`t remember why I assumed that this wouldn`t work. I will take another look at the implementation tomorrow and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can launch a new coroutine inside `repeatOnLifecycle` function scope, because `launch` function returns a `Job` so you can use it to cancel your job later.

Moreover, if you want to listen multiple flows inside `repeatOnLifecycle` scope, you'll need to launch a child coroutine to let them run in parallel. So they won't block each other and canceling a flow will not affect other flows.

Example code:

```kotlin
lateinit var job: Job

viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
    repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
        job = launch {
            flowOfInterest.collectLatest {
                if (it) {
                    stopCollection()
                    doOnTrue()
                } else {
                    doOnFalse()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func stopCollection() {
    job.cancel()
}
```

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but in this case suspend functions called from `doOnTrue` (or doOnTrue itself) are also cancelled or not?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question here. What I needed was something like a `takeWhile` operator that includes the first non-matching element. Such an opeator can be created using the `transformWhile` operator like this:

```kotlin
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
    repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
        flowOfInterest.transformWhile {
            emit(it)
            !it
        }.collectLatest {
            if (it) {
                doOnTrue()
            } else {
                doOnFalse()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is not as nice and compact as I had hoped, but it works.

Edit: Alternatively, you can use Arpit Shukla's answer and perform the actions in the predicate of the 'first' function.

Comment: Hey, could you please explain why doesn't `first` work for you?

Comment: Sure, let's discuss below your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `takeWhile` to define condition which controls collecting from flow.

```
 flowOfInterest.takeWhile { !it }.collect {
     //execute smth
 }
```

If your flow is "cold" after reaching the state, when the condition is not met, the flow will stop emitting at all if there is no more observers. Otherwise, it will continue (e.g. if you use shared flow), but your current observer (which you applied to the question) will stop collecting.

As a workaround to your specific case, if your flow is not "cold", you can call

```
flowOfInterest.take(1).collect { ... }
```

to receive the element, on which the predicate returns false.

You can also use additional boolean value that you will modify in collect block when you will reach some condition, which will be the predicate for `takeWhile`.

Comment: Thanks but this will not work for my use case since, according to the documentation, "it does *not* contain the element on which the predicate returned false".

Comment: @metrik I extended my answer, maybe it helps